# Speech recognition - hangover scheme - voice activity detection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, speech-recognition

I am doing a voice activity detection challenge, and I am asked to add a hangover scheme to the model. I read about hangover schemes in different papers but I couldn't find a definition for this. What does it consist in?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the [code](https://github.com/tldrafael/VAD-LTSE/blob/2c31fdb05e123a2ecc2de6e3a3f5b8f27d75061c/ltsd.py#L131), it is very simple:

```
def hangover(it_is_speech, ltsds, n_hangover=8, ltsd_limit=30):

    it_is_speech_ho = []
    n_silences = 0
    for i in np.arange(len(ltsds)):

        # turnoff hangovere
        if ltsds[i] > ltsd_limit:
            it_is_speech_ho.append(it_is_speech[i])
            n_silences = 0

        else :
            if it_is_speech[i] == False:
                n_silences += 1
            else:
                n_silences = 0

            if n_silences >= n_hangover:
                it_is_speech_ho.append(False)
            else:
                it_is_speech_ho.append(True)

    return it_is_speech_ho
```